# How to prevent the terminal from echoing my getopts arguments?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, getopts

I'm writing a script that includes `getopts`, and it works swimmingly:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define help function for options
function help(){
    echo
    echo -e $YELLOW'--->COMMAND LINE OPTIONS:'$ENDCOLOR
    echo
    echo "Usage example:";
    echo "script_name [(-i|--install) string] [(-u|--uninstall) string] [(-b|--backup) string] [(-r|--restore) string] [(-m|--manualupdate) string] [(-p|--passwordreset) string] [(-a|--accessdetails) string] [(-t|--updatetoolkit)] [(-U|--updateall)]";
    echo "Options:";
    echo
    echo "-i or --install string: Install an app.";
    echo "-u or --uninstall string: Uninstall an app.";
    echo "-b or --backup string: Backup an the config file for an app.";
    echo "-r or --restore string: Restore an app config file from backup.";
    echo "-m or --manualupdate string: Manually update a specific app.";
    echo "-p or --passwordreset string: Reset the password to an app.";
    echo "-a or --accessdetails string: View the access details for an app.";
    echo "-t or --updatetoolkit: Update the toolkit.";
    echo "-U or --updateall: Update Linux and all apps.";
    exit 1;
}

# Reset option vars
updatetoolkit=0;
updateall=0;

# Capture options to getopts
export ARGS=$(getopt -o "i:u:b:r:m:p:a:tUh" -l "install:,uninstall:,backup:,restore:,manualupdate:,passwordreset:,accessdetails:,updatetoolkit,updateall,help" -n "script_name" -- "$@");

if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
    help;
fi

eval set -- "$ARGS";

while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -i|--install)
            shift;
                    if [ -n "$1" ]; 
                    then
                        install="$1";
                        source $SCRIPTSOURCE/$1/$1-installer.sh
                        shift;
                    fi
            ;;
        -u|--uninstall)
            shift;
                    if [ -n "$1" ]; 
                    then
                        uninstall="$1";
                        source $SCRIPTSOURCE/$1/$1-uninstaller.sh
                        shift;
                    fi
            ;;
        -b|--backup)
            shift;
                    if [ -n "$1" ]; 
                    then
                        backup="$1";
                        source $SCRIPTSOURCE/$1/$1-constants.sh
                        source $SCRIPTPATH/inc/app-backup-controller.sh
                        shift;
                    fi
            ;;
        -r|--restore)
            shift;
                    if [ -n "$1" ]; 
                    then
                        restore="$1";
                        source $SCRIPTSOURCE/$1/$1-constants.sh
                        source $SCRIPTPATH/inc/app-restore-controller.sh
                        shift;
                    fi
            ;;
        -m|--manualupdate)
            shift;
                    if [ -n "$1" ]; 
                    then
                        manualupdate="$1";
                        source $SCRIPTSOURCE/$1/$1-updater.sh
                        shift;
                    fi
            ;;
        -p|--passwordreset)
            shift;
                    if [ -n "$1" ]; 
                    then
                        passwordreset="$1";
                        source $SCRIPTSOURCE/$1/$1-constants.sh
                        source $SCRIPTPATH/inc/app-password-reset.sh
                        shift;
                    fi
            ;;
        -a|--accessdetails)
            shift;
                    if [ -n "$1" ]; 
                    then
                        accessdetails="$1";
                        source $SCRIPTSOURCE/$1/$1-constants.sh
                        source $SCRIPTPATH/inc/app-access-details.sh
                        shift;
                    fi
            ;;
        -t|--updatetoolkit)
            shift;
                    updatetoolkit="1";
                    source $SCRIPTPATH/maintenance/update.sh
            ;;
        -U|--updateall)
            shift;
                    updateall="1";
                    source $SCRIPTPATH/maintenance/distro-update.sh
            ;;

        --)
            shift;
            break;
            ;;
    esac
done

# Check required arguments
```

However, whenever I run the script with an argument, it does what it should do, but it prints the argument in the terminal, ie:

```
-p

Remaining code...
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: `bash -x /your/script` and see where `-p` is printed.

Comment: @whjm Wow. I'm knew to bash and I forgot there was a debug flag. Turns out I had an `echo $1` in there that I didn't comment out. Thanks; if you put a quick explanation as to how `bash -x` is helpful in cases like this, I'll mark it as correct.